# Copying Specific Column from One Workbook to Another using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am fairly new to python and trying to copy the data in workbook one, columns A,D,G, paste them into columns A,B,C, on the new workbook. I know how to copy one column or the whole worksheet but can't figure that out.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb1 = load_workbook('test1.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('test2.xlsx')

ws1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
ws2 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        c = ws1.cell(row=i, column=j)
        ws2.cell(row=i, column=j).value = c.value


wb2.save('test2.xlsx')
```

That is the code I am using to copy the whole worksheet

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
for i in range(1, mr + 1):
        ws2['A' + str(i)].value = ws1['A' + str(i)].value
        ws2['B' + str(i)].value = ws1['D' + str(i)].value
        ws2['C' + str(i)].value = ws1['G' + str(i)].value
```

Comment: Would i add that in or replace `for j in range`

Comment: replace it. there’s no need to loop through each row and column as the columns are defined by the letters. Just loop through each row and do whatever operation you need to, to set the data in the equivalent row on the output worksheet.